# Oracle Function return varchar2 is ok, but return SYS_REFCURSOR get ORA-14551

Tags: oracle

Tool: Toad 9.7.2.5

I wrote 1 function which has an insert statement in it.

I execute command

```
SELECT TWO2F_QUERY_TEST ('XX', 'XX') 
  FROM DUAL;
```

When this function, which return `SYS_REFCURSOR`, I will get

> 1, N, *INSERT TWO2R063_W1 ERROR(C1-NOT USED)**ORA-14551: cannot
>   perform a DML operation inside a query

When this function, which returns `varchar2`, it will process successful

Code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TWO2F_QUERY_TEST
(PI_BUS_ID         IN  VARCHAR2 ,
 PI_TMNL_ID        IN  VARCHAR2 
)RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
--)RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
PO_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
WK_ACTION VARCHAR2(01) := 'Y';
WK_MSG    VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TWO2R063_W1
      ( R063W1_TITLE   ,
        R063W1_FORWARD
      )
    VALUES             
      ( 'PROGRAM NOT USED' ,
        'XX'            
      )
    ;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      WK_ACTION := 'N';
      WK_MSG    := SUBSTR('*INSERT TWO2R063_W1 ERROR(C1-NOT USED)'||SQLERRM, 1, 100);
      GOTO OUTER;
  <<OUTER>> 
  <<ENDRTN>>                                   

  OPEN PO_CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ROWNUM    AS PO_ROWNUM ,
           WK_ACTION AS PO_ACTION , 
           WK_MSG    AS PO_MSG   
      FROM DUAL
    ;

  RETURN PO_CURSOR;

  --RETURN 'Y';

END TWO2F_QUERY_TEST;

/
SHOW ERROR;
DROP    PUBLIC  SYNONYM TWO2F_QUERY_TEST;
CREATE  PUBLIC  SYNONYM TWO2F_QUERY_TEST FOR TWO2F_QUERY_TEST;
GRANT   EXECUTE ON TWO2F_QUERY_TEST TO GTS_AP_MAINTAIN, EGTS;
/

========================================================
DROP TABLE TWO2.TWO2R063_W1 CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TWO2.TWO2R063_W1
(R063W1_TITLE   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
 R063W1_FORWARD VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS NOCACHE;

DROP PUBLIC SYNONYM TWO2R063_W1;
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM TWO2R063_W1 FOR TWO2.TWO2R063_W1;
GRANT DELETE, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON TWO2.TWO2R063_W1 TO TWO2_MAINTAIN;
GRANT SELECT ON TWO2.TWO2R063_W1 TO TWO2_QUERY;
```

Comment: When you reference a function in a query, the function is not allowed to change database state. So if your function performs any DML operation, do not use it in a query.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `pragma autonomous_transaction` before the end of your first `begin` keyword and see.

**Example**

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TWO2F_QUERY_TEST
       (PI_BUS_ID         IN  VARCHAR2 ,
        PI_TMNL_ID        IN  VARCHAR2 
       )RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
      --)RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
       PO_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
       WK_ACTION VARCHAR2(01) := 'Y';
       WK_MSG    VARCHAR2(100);

        PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
        BEGIN
        -- Your code to insert
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are calling you function from SELECT not in type of return. Just remove DML for now and test it.
Here is my test:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION TWO2F_QUERY_TEST
RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
PO_CURSOR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

  OPEN PO_CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT ROWNUM        AS PO_ROWNUM ,
           owner         AS PO_ACTION , 
           table_name    AS PO_MSG   
      FROM all_tables
    ;

  RETURN PO_CURSOR;
END TWO2F_QUERY_TEST;
/


declare 
  cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  l_rownum number; 
  l_action varchar2(30);
  l_msg    varchar2(30);
begin
  cur := TWO2F_QUERY_TEST;
  fetch cur into l_rownum, l_action, l_msg;
  close cur;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_rownum||') '||l_action||'.'||l_msg); 
end;
/
```

Here is my output:

```
1) SYS.DUAL
```

Your problem is in calling DML from SQL. You have following options:

1) remove DML

2) do not call function from SQL

3) wrap DML into autonomous transaction if it's possible.